# jquery cache selectors best practice

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, caching

What's the best practice to cache jquery objects for the examples below. Is there a better way to do it?

1)

```
var content='<div id="content">'+
            '<div id="div1"></div>'+
            '<div id="div2"></div>'+
            '<div id="div3"></div>'+
            '</div>';
$('body').append(content);
var $div1=$('#div1'),
    $div2=$('#div2'),
    $div3=$('#div3');
```

2)

```
var div1='<div id="div1"></div>',
    div2='<div id="div2"></div>',
    div3='<div id="div3"></div>',
    content='<div id="content">'+div1+div2+div3+'div>';  
$('body').append(content);
var $div1=$(div1),
    $div2=$(div2),
    $div3=$(div3);
```

Comment: The second example won't work

Comment: The second one creates **new** DIVs when it assigns to `$divN`, they're not the same as the DIVs that you appended to the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3) the third choose:

```
var $div1 = $('<div id="div1"></div>'),
    $div2 = $('<div id="div2"></div>'),
    $div3 = $('<div id="div3"></div>'),
    $content = $('<div id="content">').append(div1, div2, div3).appendTo("body");
```

as a bonus tip: you might not have to cache the divs and could avoid more memory if you are doing something that could be dedicated functions .. example:

```
$content.on('click', 'div', function(){
    // you clicked on some div even if the listener is on the $content
    // 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You will not notice any performance benefit from caching the selectors or element collections in this case because selecting an element by id is already very fast.

The second case of course isn't caching at all, so it isn't even comparable to the first.

Answer (score 0):

The first is the correct way to do it.

The second way wouldn't work anyway, even if it did then that would only allow you to cache elements that you originally created in JS, not anything that was originally in the DOM